# Why is this not working? Entities.CurHP - Entities.RIntDamage

Tags: c#

Both are integers, but it keeps giving me the error

> "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement"

I have tried using different operators but none give me my desired answer.  If Entities.RIntDamage = 5 and Entities.CurHP = 10 shouldnt the answer be 5?

Comment: What do you think that line does?

Comment: Subtracts Entities.RIntDamage from Entities.CurHP ?

Comment: And then what?  What's the point of subtracting a number if you never look at the result?

Comment: Sorry @SLaks I assumed it would change the Entities.CurHP, All fixed now tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you aren't actually *doing* anything.

As the error is trying to tell you, statements in C# must have some kind of effect.
Writing `a - b` has no effect.

You might want to store the result of that in a variable, or pass it to a function.

Comment: Entities.RIntDamage - Entities.CurHP = Entities.CurHP; But this gives me the same error...

Comment: Write it the other way around: `Entities.CurHP = Entities.CurHP - Entities.RIntDamage;`

Answer (score 0):

> I assumed it would change the Entities.CurHP

Your assumption is reasonable, but requires slightly different syntax.  Use `-=` instead of `-`.  That is, use:

```
Entities.CurHP -= Entities.RIntDamage;
```

The `=` tells C# to store the result (in `Entities.CurHP`).

Similarly, `Entities.CurHP -= 6 + 5;` would subtract 11 from `Entities.CurHP` and store the result in `Entities.CurHP`.